# In processing, how can I create a method that searches one array for its largest value?

Tags: java, arrays, processing, midi

I'm trying to create a method that searches the volume array for the largest value and returns the value in the corresponding position of the note array.

Also, separately, how could I modify it so that it only plays the loudest note

```
import arb.soundcipher.*;
SoundCipher midi;

String[] note = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#",
                 "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};
float[] volume = {80,  100,  75,   43,  40,  81,  100,
                  60,   90,  30,   75,  52};
float[] duration = {1.3,   2, 0.5,    3, 0.9,   1, 0.25,
                    0.6, 1.5,   3, 1.25,   2};

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  midi = new SoundCipher(this);
  int i = (int) random(note.length);
  midi.playNote(MIDIValue(note[i]),volume[i],duration[i]);
}

float MIDIValue(String aNote) {
  float noteMIDIValue = 0.0;
  int i;
  for (i =0; i < note.length && !note[i].equals(aNote) ; i++); 
  if(i < note.length) {
     noteMIDIValue = i+60;
  }
  return noteMIDIValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

traverse the `volume` array and keep track of maximum volume and `id`(index). And finally, return the `note` corresponding to the maximum element id (`node[id]`).

Method implementation ...

```
String findLargestVolumeNote() {
    int maxId = 0;
    float maxVol = volume[0];
    // searching array for loudest volume
    for(int i = 0; i < volume.length; i++) {
        if(volume[i] > maxVol) {
            maxId = i;
            maxVol = volume[i];
        } 
    }
    return note[maxId]; // returning corrsponding note
}
```